# how to save process.env.NODE_ENV to store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So the main question is how do I save it so that when I run `npm run build` it doesn't include development only code.

Example:

store

```
var state = {
    live = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development"
}
```

usage:

```
data () {
    let live = this.$store.state.General.live
    return {
        example: live ? "production" : "development"    
    }

}
```

in the `app.js` build you will still see `example: live ? "production" : "development"` however if I were to run it like this in data

```
let live = process.env.NODE_ENV

 example: live ? "production" : "development"
```

This will remove the `live ...` from the actual build and only output `example:"production"`

So overall, is it possible to save the state of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to a store variable?

Comment: No. The app is running in a browser not on node.js. `NODE_ENV`. is being read by the build tool. It is preprocessed

Comment: The environment variable, by its name, suggest it is stored in your environment, which means stored in your server not in your code.  If your server allow you to use the external file as an env loader, than you can play tricks to change your env file, but it is generally not recommended.

Comment: @AluanHaddad not exactly what I mean. What I mean is that it's still creating a `example: live ? "production" : "development"` into my actual app.js file, whereas I would like it to only output `example: "production"` to save some bytes. The second example only works when I use `process.env.NODE_ENV` from within the template

Comment: So you want it to be processed and inlined during the build step?

Comment: Yeah I know it you want to customize your complied output, maybe babel or WebPack can play that trick. But I have to be honest, it essentially allow your complier to change your coding logic, I don't think you should do it like this.  I will suggest you isolate your variable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think so yeah. I mean, I guess it's no big deal adding a `live = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development"` at the start of every data since I'm basically doing the same thing with the store anyway

Comment: @LeoLi I already am, this is just more of a curious question of different behaviours

Comment: I didn't know the use case because you didn't state it. There are so many ways to do that....  but don't repeat yourself

Comment: But if you fallback and think twice, you actually don't want this, how your compiler will have a clue about your variable is always static???